# British English for "holding someone to account for ..."?

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrase-usage

I frequently hear the phrase "holding [someone] to account [for]" in American media (for example, this [Sam Seder video](https://youtu.be/btGW9ri2BAo?t=3m24s)) and I am under the impression that I have never heard it in British media. Wiktionary defines [hold to account](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hold_to_account) as follows:

> (*transitive*) To require a person to explain or to accept responsibility for his or her actions; to blame or punish someone for what has occurred.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20to%20account) defines it as "to hold responsible" (which is less helpful than Wiktionary). I could not find the phrase in [this online Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hold) or in my old edition of the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary (1989).

So what would be the British English equivalent of "to hold [someone] to account"? Simply, "to hold [someone] responsible"?

Comment: Strangely enough, the BrE equivalent is "to hold [someone] to account."

Comment: Interestingly enough, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-brought-called-to-account) lists this phase as "mainly UK"

Answer (score 2):

The passive form is more regularly met with than the active in the UK. Other than the following definition from Collins Cobuild, and a lack of the active form being mentioned, I don't think I'll find very satisfying supporting references for this.

> **be called/held/brought to account**  phrase
>
> If someone is called, held, or brought to account for something they
>   have done wrong, they are made to explain why they did it, and are
>   often criticized or punished for it.
>
> *Ministers should be called to account for their actions.* [+ for]

[COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-called-held-brought-to-account)